# What is the object model for the project.assets.json and what library can we use to parse it from the file?

Tags: .net-core, nuget

And I am not talking about Newtonsoft.Json - I want the actual object model that is tailored to project.assets.json

Is there a library for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After poking around the [dotnet/sdk](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk) repository, I eventually found a reference to the [NuGet/NuGet.Client](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client) repository, which defines a [`LockFile` class](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.ProjectModel/LockFile/LockFile.cs) that contains many of the same properties as a `project.assets.json` file.

Turns out this class is published in the [NuGet.ProjectModel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.ProjectModel/) package. Also turns out this package also includes classes to turn this file into an object model.

Sample code that "serializes" the file contents into an object model:

```cs
using NuGet.ProjectModel;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("my-folder/project.assets.json");
        var lockFileFormat = new LockFileFormat();
        var lockFile = lockFileFormat.Parse(content, "In Memory");
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked at this class, but since it was not mentioning assets and only lock file I assumed it is not suitable. Should have tried. I will try it now.

Comment: Yup, so far so good. My knowledge of nuget is not sufficient enough to recognize that the lock file and the project.assets.json are the same.

Comment: The name `LockFile` has been retained for backwards compatiblity. 

In project.json, it used to be named `project.lock.json`. 

Now they are different files, so you have: 
`LockFile` - project.assets.json
`PackagesLockFile` - packages.lock.json, https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.ProjectModel/ProjectLockFile/PackagesLockFile.cs